# No ability to choose Open/Close status

Tags: entries, status

With all of your help, I was able to port the live site to a development area and I thank you for all of your help.

This morning, I updated some images and, after submitting the changes, I went to look on the front facing portion of the dev site. Only the page was coming up, like a page set to close status.

I went back into the entry > Options > and there is nothing to select - Open/Closed are not available.

This was followed by going to Admin> Channel Administration> Status> and both options are available.

I went to check other entries that I did not update any images and Open/Close - the status was available.

After which, I went into the db and ran this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `exp_channel_titles`
WHERE STATUS = ""
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The result set matched the entries that I was having issues with, and I changed the entries to status of "open" and everything is working as it should, which leads to my question.

What would prevent the status from being written to the database? Is there a file that I missed setting the permissions to 666 or 777?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused because a "Status Group" isn't selected for the channel.

To check this, go to `Admin > Channel Administration > Channels`, then click on "Edit Group Assignments" for the channel having the issues. Your channel probably has "None" set for the "Status Groups". Change that to "Default Status Group" and click the Update button.

Comment: I am running v2.3.1 and I am only seeing the options of "None" and "Statuses"

Comment: Sounds like someone renamed the default group. "Statuses" is what you want selected.

Comment: How do I correct that? What table? And is that not effecting all the other entries. Why are all the other entries able to read this attribute? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Anna, I took your advice and changed the default group to "Statuses," instead of "none" and it worked. Now, when I make any change to an entry, the entry is set to open. I wish could give me a complete explanation of why this works

Comment: A Status group must be selected on for all channels. When one isn't, EE defaults to setting entries to "closed", hence your closed entries.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but they were neither closed nor open - it was blank. On our production site, I did not have to do this. It is set to "none" for the status group, that is why I am puzzled as to why this worked and I thank you for your patience in explaining